# Open gallery except .gif images

Tags: android, camera, gallery

I want to open device gallery except **.gif images**.

I tried the following code but it showing all images in gallery, let me help

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >21){
    pickPhoto.setType("image/*");
    pickPhoto.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
}
startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

Comment: You should use the custom view to view the device data, custom view means you have to create the separate screen for viewing yours images or viedos...i have also used these approch

Comment: thanks to replay but i want to use default gallery.

Comment: ok...Are you gettting the images with gif ??

Comment: yes..and i don't want to display gif based images in gallery while selecting image.

Comment: ok..let me check the code once

Answer (score 4):

To open the device gallery except for **.gif images**, you need to set the supported **mimeTypes** for the gallery intent i.e., image types you need to pick from the gallery like png, jpg, jpeg, etc.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"};
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
```